# table which contains only primary keys of other tables, does this table need its own primary key

Tags: database, data-binding

I am creating one table which contains only primary keys of other three tables. should i keep primary key for this table also?

Comment: yes, you should. It's a good practice.

Comment: but whenever i'll refer to record, i'll be checking primary key of other table. so i thought i may not need to create primary key for this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and its primary key should consist of those three foreign keys.

```
create table foo (
  pk_1 whatever_type not null references table_1 (pk_1),
  pk_2 whatever_type not null references table_2 (pk_2),
  pk_3 whatever_type not null references table_3 (pk_3),
  primary key (pk_1, pk_2, pk_3)
);
```